# What is the origin of Mina Harker being Dracula's wife?

Tags: history-of, dracula

I've come across two adaptations of Bram Stoker's novel [*Dracula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracula), namely the 1992 film [*Bram Stoker's Dracula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bram_Stoker%27s_Dracula) and the 2013 TV series [*Dracula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracula_(TV_series)), which feature a common plot point. In both, the character Mina Harker is portrayed as the reincarnation of Dracula's long-dead wife.

My question is, is there any hint of Mina Harker being the reincarnation of Dracula's wife in Bram Stoker's original novel?  If not, what is the origin of this notion?  Did it originate with the 1992 film, or was it there before that?

Comment: It's been a while since I read the novel, but I don't remember this plot point being present in the original text.  I could be mistaken, though.

Comment: I THINK I remember it being an element in Saberhagen's 'The Holmes-Dracula File', but I haven't read it in years, so I'm not positive.

Answer (score 5):

Mina Harker was not the reincarnation of Dracula's wife in the original novel.

As I remember, in the *Dark Shadows* TV series there may have been a plot in which Victoria Winters in the 1960s was considered to be the reincarnation of vampire Barnabus Collins's fiance Josette  from the 1790s.  In *House of Dark Shadows* (1970) Barnabus Collins believes that Maggie Evans may be the reincarnation of his lost Josette who she closely resembles.

IN the comedy *Love at First Bite* (1979) Dracula in 1979 New York City believes that model Cindy Sonheim, like Mina Harker earlier, is the reincarnation of his true love.

I am not an expert on vampire and Dracula movies, but it seem possible that Dan Curtis and the writers of *Dark Shadows* created the idea of a modern woman being the reincarnation of a vampire's lost love, and that *Love at First Bite* (1979) was the first Dracula movie using that plot.

Comment: While not exactly Dracula, Blackula (1972) had the title character meet (who he thinks is) the reincarnation of his wife in 1970s Los Angeles.  This plot point might have bled into later films.

Answer (score 3):

Dan Curtis' *Dracula* (1974 Television movie)?

This made-for-TV version of Dracula was directed by Dan Curtis, the man who brought us *Dark Shadows*, and as M.A. Golding pointed out in his answer, I think the romantic sub plot was brought over by Curtis and he may have talked Richard Matheson, the author of the teleplay, into including it in his story. The difference in this version is that the Count sees his lost love in Lucy instead of Mina. Here is a paragraph from one of the user reviews on IMDb.

"Other fans of DARK SHADOWS will recognize the lost-love element as having come from Barnabas Collins' tragic situation in that series. It adds a magnificent new element to the Dracula story without diluting the original. Bob Cobert's music, also familiar to DARK SHADOWS fans, is the perfect accompaniment to the tale of the vampire count. I have watched this numerous times since it became available on tape."

Here is the TV trailer from YouTube which includes clips of scenes in which Dracula was remembering his lost love.

The idea of a reincarnated lost love was not present in the original novel "Count Dracula", but I think this was the earliest movie version to include it.

Answer (score 0):

The origins of Mina being Dracula’s wife may spring from Stoker’s own *Dracula*, Chapter 21, where the author seems to play with this idea.  Dracula first bites Mina’s neck and drinks her blood and then he forces Mina to drink his blood and from then on, somehow, the two of them remain in a constant mental link with each other. The group of men, led by Van Helsing, then use this link against Dracula, to ultimately track him down and kill him, and thus sever this “blood link” between Mina and Dracula.